# Objective-c class exposed via bridging header not visible from swift when archiving release

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

In my react native project, I try to expose a swift function to the javascript code. It works well in debug mode, but when trying to archiving I get a `Use of undeclared type RCTEventEmitter` error on my swift file.

The `RCTEventEmitter` is imported in my `RNUtils.m` file, and in the bridging header.

So I guess somewhere in the archiving, something fail with the bridging header, but I have no idea where.
If I ask for a non existing import, it will tell me that it can't compile the bridging header, so the file is taken into account during the build.

```
// Utils.m
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTConvert.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_MODULE(RNUtils, RNUtils, RCTEventEmitter)

@end
```

```
// Utils.swift
import Foundation

@objc(RNUtils)
class RNUtils: RCTEventEmitter {
  // my native code emitting events
}
```

```
// MyApp-Bridging-header.h
#ifndef MyApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

#endif
```

- react-native 0.61.5
- xcode 11.5
- Swift 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I needed to add ìmport React` in every swift file. It's archiving fine now.

Comment: I am currently dealing with this same issue, but "import React" results in "No such module React". Furthermore other related issues seem to say that in recent versions of react, all of this should be handled with "pod install" automatically. Did you have to do anything special to enable importing React?

Comment: did you `import React` inside pod file? I have same problem but it's from cocoapod